# Typescript's Excess Property Check failing when passed an indexed type

Tags: typescript

I recently got caught out by passing an indexed object to a method that takes an interface with wholly optional properties. I would have hoped that this would have caused an excess property check type warning, but Typescript let it go without error.

Here's a minimal case:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
}

interface IndexedInterface {
  [c: string]: SomeInterface;
}

// ...

function fn(t: SomeInterface) {
  console.log(typeof t.a); // should always be "string"
}

const something: SomeInterface = {
  a: 'string',
  b: 1,
};

const indexedThing: IndexedInterface = {
  a: something,
};

fn(something);    // no error, output: "string", this is fine
fn(indexedThing); // no error, output: "object", this is not fine
```

Is there some way I could make Typescript warn about these cases, or can someone explain why I can legally pass `indexedThing` to a function that expects `SomeInterface`?

Comment: FYI this isn't about excess property checks (which only apply to object literals) but about the surprising assignability of weak types (with all optional properties) to all index-signature types.

Comment: I *think* this might be a compiler bug (seems to be related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9900 but not sure)

Comment: I agree with jcalz, this looks like a bug, you can fully disallow something with a string index signature with something like `function fn<T extends SomeInterface>(t: T & (string extends keyof T ? "No index signature allowed" : {})) {
  
}`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that someone may have thought about the behavior at some point: "The weak type check occurs when the target is a weak type and the source has at least one property, call signature or construct signature" ([this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16047#issue-122101801)).  But the rule still makes no sense to me.  I went ahead and filed [a new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27144).  If you add a property (even an optional one) to `IndexedInterface`, then the error is reported as expected.